# Homeomorphism equicontinuous not isometric

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, dynamical-systems

Let $(X,d)$ compact metric space. We say that a homeomorphims $f:X\mapsto X$ is equicontinuous if $\{f^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an equicontinuous family.

I would like to find examples of such homeomorphisms but non-isometries.

I appreciate any reference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S^1$ denote the circle, and let $d$ denote the standard metric on it. Let $d'$ be another metric on $S^1$, which is not a multiple of $d$ by a constant. Define $\varphi:S^1\to S^1$ to be "rotation by 180 degrees" with respect to the metric $d'$. That is, $\varphi$ maps a point $p\in S^1$ to the point farthest from $p$ with respect to $d'$. Then $\varphi$ is not an isometry with respect to $d$, but it is certainly equicontinuous, as $\varphi^2=id$.

Comment: Nice solution+1